# Change TYPO3 mail settings for StartTLS

Tags: typo3

I'm a newbie to TYPO3 so excuse me if something is wrong on the following lines.

I've set TYPO3 10.4.34 + Powermail 8.3.3 + DirectMail 7.0.1.

Some changes happened on our mail provider: from now we should use the StartTLS protocol and send via 587 port (oAuth2 auth.).

Obviously now the old TYPO3 configuration doesn't send anything: I guess that I must edit the LocalConfiguration.php and/or the LocalConfiguration.sendmail.php (why two localconf?) in the MAIL section.

Do you know what lines should I add for sending mail successfully?
I guess I must edit the line:

`'transport_smtp_encrypt' => false,`

in LocalConfiguration.php putting it true.

Instead the line in the same file:

`'transport_smtp_server' => 'smtp.MY_ADDRESS:587',`

seems OK to me but where can I add (if necessary) the info about the StartTLS protocol?

Thanks,
Fabianope

PS: For now I've tried nothing: please can you confirm that my findings are good?

Comment: Guessing - Microsoft Office 365 ?

Answer (score 0):

TYPO3 manages its Mail settings Centrally. so it does not matter what plugin, or service want to send a mail.

these settings are usally written to LocalConfiguration.php. usually you should not edit that manually but rather use the Installtool / Admin tools to modify settings and that will rewrite them.

normaly there should be no LocalConfiguration.sendmail.php

TYPO3 only loads `LocalConfiguration.php` than `AdditionalConfiguration.php` and after that all configuration from extensions wich define an `ext_localconf.php`

AdditionalConfiguration.php is maintiend by the Admin. so you could include Abritray php code. (like switch configuration based on Envirionment)

Since TYPO3 v11 the MAIL settings are very well documented:
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/11.5/en-us/Configuration/Typo3ConfVars/MAIL.html

and the relevant settings should be the same.

you most likly want to set `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['MAIL']['transport_smtp_encrypt']` to FALSE as it disables STARTTSL https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/11.5/en-us/Configuration/Typo3ConfVars/MAIL.html#transport-smtp-encrypt

Comment: Thanks for your comments but if you take a look to:
http://www.fabianope.net/encrypt.JPG
you can see that I can't change this setting within the "Configure Installation-Wide Options".
Is it any reason for this?
Thanks,
Fabianope

Answer (score 0):

I have never head of `LocalConfiguration.sendmail.php`. I assume it's a file that has been created by the developer who has made your website and it's included in `LocalConfiguration.php`.

Nevertheless, you need to change `transport_smtp_encrypt` to `true` as you already suggested and set `transport_smtp_server`, `transport_smtp_username` and `transport_smtp_password`. That can be done via the TYPO3 Install Tool or directly in `LocalConfiguration.php`.

Afterwards you can check your mail settings by sending a mail from "Admin Tools" => "Environment" => "Test Mail Setup".

Comment: Thanks for your comments but if you take a look to: fabianope.net/encrypt.JPG you can see that I can't change this setting within the "Configure Installation-Wide Options". Is it any reason for this? Thanks, Fabianope

Answer (score 0):

Resolved with:

```
'transport_smtp_server' => 'smtp.office365.com:587'
```

and

```
'transport_smtp_encrypt' => false
```

please note the lack of quotes on "false": it seems that TYPO3 wants so.

Thanks a lot,
Fabianope